# Power query conditional max min date

Tags: excel-2013, powerquery

I'm using PowerQuery 2013, and I'm new to it.

Here is a sample of my data:

[image: need to remove yellow rows]

I need to crop the dates in Power Query, on market level, to include only overlapping range of dates (can't just delete rows with nulls - it's OK to have nulls inside data range).

I have found a number of articles to use functions but I'm just not good enough to adapt them to my situation.

I tried to create a function (called MaxDate) and then create a column in my data invoking this function:

MaxDate function query:

```
(table as table, mkt as text) => Table.Max(Table.SelectRows(table, [Market]=mkt))[Date]
```

Invoke the function in a new column:

```
= Table.AddColumn(Sales, "GetMaxDate", each MaxDate(Sales, [Market])[Date])
```

This returned "Error" and I can't resolve it. I was going to generate min/max date columns, and then filter out dates that fell outside as a final output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting the syntax like this:

```
(table as table, mkt as text) => Table.Max(Table.SelectRows(table, each [Market]=mkt), "Date")
```

Comment: It worked!!!!!!!!!!!!!   Thanks!!!! :-)  Only one quirk, it returns a column with "record" which I then need to expand to pick Date column (a bit like a merged table expand). Is there a way to return just the date value and not the whole row?

Comment: Yes, just add: [Date]{0} at the end - it will lookup the first row's value in the column [Date]: (table as table, mkt as text) => Table.Max(Table.SelectRows(table, each [Market]=mkt), "Date") [Date]{0}

Answer (score 0):

OK take 2 ...

I think you may be overcomplicating it.  With the data in the shape you indicated, I would start a new Query referring to that dataset. I would then Group By [Market] and aggregate the Max and Min of [Date].  I would set that Query to Load To = Only Create Connection.

Then I would start a new Query by reference to the original dataset.  I would use a Merge to join it to the Max/Min Query just created, joining on [Market].  Then I would Add a Calculated filter column e.g.

`if [Date] = [Min Date] or [Date] = [Max Date]`

Finally I would filter on the added column - keeping the FALSE values.

Comment: thanks, but that would be eliminating rows with null inside the timeline, and i need to cut off only the "ends".

Comment: OK I didn't understand the requirement.  I've rewritten my answer.

Comment: Mike i had tried this, it takes ages as i need to do it with 2 large datasources. It takes about the same time to do it via a function but is simpler to implement, so i chose ImkeF's answer. I am grateful for the ideas! :)